# Finding global minimum and maximum for a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $f(x, y) = y^2 x-y x^2+xy $

Find the global minimum and maximum of f on the domain

$ D={(x,y): -1<=x<=0, 0<=y<=x+1} $

I know how to find the maximimum and minimium by using partial derivatives i am however unsure how the inequality between y and x will affect this and if i should change my aproach

Comment: FYI use \ge for greater than or equal to like this $\$\text{\ge}\$\to\, \ge$.

Comment: Your approach will work fine to see if the global min/max is inside the boundaries. Furthermore, you will have to test **each** boundary line and **each** corner if there is no global min/max in the domain or for the function at all, and see where on the boundaries, and at which corner, the function attains a _local_ min/max.